# Redirecting domains in local server with Wordpress installations

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Uniserver as local server and have several sub-directories under `www` that simulate each one a different domain.

Example:

`http://localhost/WPTest/` is the WPTest site where there is a Wordpress installation

`http://localhost/WPTest1/` is the WPTest1 site where there is another Wordpress installation

What I would like to do and haven't been able, is to redirect  `http://localhost/WPTest/` just to `http://WPTest` and `http://localhost/WPTest1/` just to `http://WPTest1`, etc.

I will appreciate any help to do this or at least to tell me if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Uniserver do the work for you:

Create a `Virtual Host` opening `Server Configuration -> Apache -> Apache Vhosts`

Enter the `Document Root` path (i.e. ./whatever/www/WPTest).

Enter the `Server Name` (i.e. "wptest"). Use lower case only.

Select `Confirm`

Restart Apache Server.

Now in Wordpress, go to `http://localhost/WPTest/wp-admin`.

In `Settings -> General`, modify:

`WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` replacing the actual URLs with  `http://wptest`

Restart WP.

That's all. Now the virtual Wordpress site is accessed at `http://wptest`

Repeat the same steps for each subdirectory.